# Can't send Alertmanager alerts on Mattermost with button in it

Tags: configuration, prometheus-alertmanager, mattermost, kube-prometheus-stack

### Problem

I'm trying to send an alerts from Alertmanager to Mattermost with button in the message but it didn't work. I'm using the

### Context

I'm deploying Alertmanager with the kube-prometheus-stack HELM chart on Kubernetes.

`values.yaml`:

```yaml
## Configuration for alertmanager
## ref: https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/alertmanager/
##
alertmanager:
  ## Alertmanager configuration directives
  ## ref: https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#configuration-file
  ##      https://prometheus.io/webtools/alerting/routing-tree-editor/
  ##
  config:
    route:
      receiver: "<RECEIVER_NAME>"
      routes:
      - receiver: "<RECEIVER_NAME>"
        match:
          severity = "critical"
    receivers:
      - name: "<RECEIVER_NAME>"
        slack_configs:
            # Whether to notify about resolved alerts.
          - send_resolved: true
            icon_url: https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/3380462
            color: '{{ template "slack.color" . }}'
            title: '{{ template "slack.title" . }}'
            text: '{{ template "slack.text" . }}'
            #  Didn't work at the moment
            actions:
              - type: button
                text: 'Query :mag:'
                url: '{{ (index .Alerts 0).GeneratorURL }}'
              - type: button
                text: 'Dashboard :chart_with_upwards_trend:'
                url: '{{ (index .Alerts 0).Annotations.dashboard_url }}'
              - type: button
                text: 'Silence :no_bell:'
                url: '{{ template "__alert_silence_link" . }}'
            # The Slack webhook URL. Either api_url or api_url_file should be set.
            # Defaults to global settings if none are set here.
            api_url: <MATTERMOST_WEBHOOK_URL>
            # The HTTP client's configuration.
            http_config:
              proxy_url: '<HTTP_PROXY>'
```

I'm using a HTTP_PROXY to be able to join Mattermost.

### Version

- Kubernetes: 1.28
- Kube-prometheus-stack: 55.11.0 (HELM chart)
- Mattermost: 9.1.1

### Behaviour

Notification are sended to Mattermost without the button notification.

### What I tried ?

I tried to had a `name` field on each button but it doesn't work

Tell me if you need more information.